# PHP sprintf output 2 decimals

Tags: php, decimal

I am working some code in php and I found this problem:

```
$a = 4.60;
$b = 5.05; 
$c = 2.60;

$r = ($a + $b + $c) * 0.1;

echo "r: $r\n";
echo "r sprintf1: " . sprintf("%.2f",$r) . "\n";
echo "r sprintf2: " . sprintf("%.2f",1.225) . "\n";
```

The output is:

```
r: 1.225
r sprintf1: 1.22
r sprintf2: 1.23
```

As you can see, sprintf behaves different when the result should be the same. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will find this can be put down to IEEE Floating point number and there little foibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because floating point values are not exact, and doing math with them only compounds the inexactitude.

```
$a = 4.60;
$b = 5.05; 
$c = 2.60;

$r = ($a + $b + $c) * 0.1;

// greatly increase the floating point display precision
ini_set('precision', 30);

var_dump( $a, $b, $c, $r, 1.225 );
```

Output:

```
float(4.59999999999999964472863211995)
float(5.04999999999999982236431605997)
float(2.60000000000000008881784197001)
float(1.22499999999999986677323704498)
float(1.22500000000000008881784197001)
```

Which is why you should you should *never* use floats for representing money.

http://moneyphp.org/

Answer (score 0):

when you are calculating floating point (`$r = ($a + $b + $c) * 0.1;`) it's result is not exactly 1.225 rather it is something like `1.22499999999999986677323704498`. that's why it happen.

> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality.

You can read more details in the official documentation from here  [Floating point precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: `1.22499999999999986677323704498`